# Python Pandas changing rows values in a column for a slice of rows

Tags: pandas, slice

I am following a tutorial and trying to reset some values in a Pandas dataframe with the following line of code

0. ```
    df['Geography'][30:50] = np.nan     # to reset the values in the Geography column to NaN for a slice of rows
   ```

This generates a SettingWithCopyWarning despite doing what I want it to do

I have tried to look up the correct syntax to avoid the warning and found two possible solutions

1. ```
    df[30:50]['Geography'] = np.nan          # this didn't work !!
   ```

and using .loc, which seems to be the prefered solution

2. ```
     df.loc['Geography'][30:50] = np.nan         # but which is generating a KeyError: 'Geography'
   ```

Can anyone offer a pointer or two

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR : `df.loc[30:50, 'Geography'] = np.nan`


`df[30:50]['Geography'] = np.nan` does not work because when you use the syntax `df[<name>]`, `<name>` should be a column name whereas in your use it is a slice of the index. 
`df.loc['Geography'][30:50] = np.nan` almost the same error, when you use `.loc`, you must give index names or a slice as the first element of the tuple. 
Best solution : `df.loc[30:50, 'Geography'] = np.nan`

Feel free to take a look at the [pandas indexing docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-label)

Comment: Thanks for this. I'd played around with several formats. I do need to get better at looking at the documentation.